# SQL - Deletar registros que possuem campo com o mesmo valor de outro, somente quando houver mais de um registro

Tags: mysql, sql, firebird

Tenho uma tabela de código de barras de produtos, quero deletar apenas os códigos de barra que sejam iguais ao código do produto e que tenham outro código além deste. Tabela:

```
CodProduto    CodBarra
    01           01      < não deletar
    02           02      < deletar
    02         789123    < não deletar
    02         789124    < não deletar
    03           03      < não deletar
    04           04      < deletar
    04         789125    < não deletar
    04         789126    < não deletar
```

Tentei de alguns modos, mas sempre acabo deletando todos os código de barras que sejam iguais ao código do produto.
Vocês tem uma idéia ou sabem se isto é possível ou não?

Comment: Afinal o `SGBD` é `Firebird` ou `MySQL`?

Comment: Firebird. Mas uso o MySQL em outro projeto e é útil saber do mesmo modo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a cláusula `WHERE` normalmente para verificar se o código é igual ao código de barras e depois verificar se existe outro registro com a condição inversa:

```
DELETE t1
  FROM tabela t1
 WHERE t1.CodProduto = t1.CodBarra
   AND EXISTS(SELECT 1
                FROM tabela t2
               WHERE t2.CodProduto = t1.CodProduto
                 AND t2.CodProduto <> t2.CodBarra)
```

Comment: Ótimo. Isto mesmo que preciso. Muito obrigado!